# How to do-release-upgrade with automatic yes to all continue and disable reboot after upgrade completion

Tags: upgrade, reboot, release-management, do-release-upgrade

How do I disable reboot after `do-release-upgrade`? Is that even possible?

How do I automatically answer `y` to all continue during do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: try `echo Y | do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an app for that! Well, for answering `y` automatically anyway:

```
NAME
       yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
```

So, you could do

```
yes | do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Does not do the trick on 12.04, just says `Must be connected to a terminal.`.